# Passing by Reference is failed?

Tags: php

When I used PHP to Manipulate arrays,I got a problem!

How does this work?

I want to know why!

And I found if I dont use 'unset',this code can work! And I google ,but doesn't get answer!
So I ask!

When I use Passing by Reference in PHP.It's failed!

Thanks!

```
<?php

$arr = array('a','b','c','d',array(1,2,3,4,5));

var_dump($arr);
foreach($arr as &$value){
    if($value == 'c'){
        unset($value);
    }
    if(is_array($value)){
        foreach ($value as $key => &$v) {
            if($v == 2){
                unset($v);
            }
        }
    }
}
var_dump($arr);

?>
```

This is Result:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string 'b' (length=1)
  2 => string 'c' (length=1)
  3 => string 'd' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 2
      2 => int 3
      3 => int 4
      4 => int 5
array (size=5)
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string 'b' (length=1)
  2 => string 'c' (length=1)
  3 => string 'd' (length=1)
  4 => &
    array (size=5)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 2
      2 => int 3
      3 => int 4
      4 => &int 5
```

Comment: What is "failed"? The code is syntactically correct

Comment: nope. He's trying to unset a virtual variable. You have to unset the actual array by key name.

Comment: I suppose it is syntactically correct. my bad. just not correct.

Comment: @zerkms beacuse the unset doesn't work.

Comment: @MarshallHouse Yes,it's work,but I want to know why this doesn't.

Comment: @user2158948: next time explain it a bit more detailed - `unset` does work, and it works correctly. But what you expect is something else :-)

Comment: @zerkms Yes.my fault!Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove an item from the array you're iterating over - you need to `unset` array's key, not its value:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if (...) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
```

Your current solution doesn't work as you expect because `&$value` on any particular iteration is another reference to the same variable stored in `$arr`. So you're unsetting the local variable, not the original.

Comment: Thanks for help！ I did not understand Passing by Reference!Sorry!